# SIGWINCH ignored. Not daemonized

Tags: django, gunicorn

I keep getting the following in my gunicorn log:

```
SIGWINCH ignored. Not daemonized
```

I am running gunicorn via `./manage.py run_gunicorn --workers=4` in a `screen`.

What does this message mean? Should I be worried?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is this issue on Github explained ([Issue Link](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/449))

This happen if the terminal is resized